# Codeigniter and Bootstrap installation using composer

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

I have created a Codeigniter project and installed Bootstrap library using composer. I use `composer create-project CodeIgniter/framework [project-name]` for composer installation and `composer require twbs/bootstrap` for Bootstrap library. I want to how I compile this project? How I use Bootstrap into view folder? and after completing the project what will be the deployment process?